# Command like "ember s" gets stuck and not loading

Tags: node.js, npm, ember.js, frontend, ember-cli

I’ve been following Getting started: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/getting-started/quick-start/.

I did:

```
npm install -g ember-cli
ember new ember-quickstart
cd ember-quickstart
ember serve
```

After *ember serve* or *server* or *ember s*, It just keeps loading and never load server.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: install dependencies  `cd ember-quickstart` `npm install`

Comment: `ember new` already installs dependencies after generating the project.

Comment: Can you provide some more context? Maybe paste what the terminal outputs from when you do `ember serve`?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. I had virus and had to change harddisk to get rid of it.

Everything works fine now and I'm rocking Ember Apps